# HtmlUnitWebdriver in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way that I can execute javascript completely which contains Ajax calls in HtmlUnit webdriver ?  As it is invisible driver we are not able to track its working.
 I dont expect answers as

```
  Webdriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
   or
  driver.setjavascriptenabled(true);
```

Please if any one is knowing HtmlUnit's internal working , any help , i truely appreciate it as i am facing the problem.

Comment: This makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to automate/work with plus.google.com. I got it correctly from Firefox but when i use htmlUnit i fail with same code. The above code is written but still i fail with HtmlUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't investigated  HtmlUnit webdriver  deeply but  jsExecutor was quite enough for me for js execution .
E.g.

```
String cssLocator=.... 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssLocator+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: I will check out this one . Thanks for your reply.